# rendering forms with flask + wtform

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

code in question:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
import os
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
from models import Member
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form
@simple_page.route('/register')
def register():
    form = model_form(Member, Form)
    return render_template('register.html', form=form, name="bad")


class Member(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

and in my view:

```
        <p class="txt11 colorb">
        {{ form.name }}
        </p>
```

this outputs `<UnboundField(TextField, (), {u'default': None, u'filters': [], u'validators': [<wtforms.validators.Required object at 0x7f62f59b5590>, <wtforms.validators.Length object at 0x7f62f59b55d0>]})>`, not an actual field. how do i get an actual form/field with the wtform?

Comment: Can you update your question with the imports that you are using?

Comment: i've added the imports

Comment: From where are you importing `model_form`?

Comment: Try changing it to `form = model_form(Member, base_class=Form)` I believe you have a version issue.

Comment: i've added that, and it still doesn't work. is it okay that my model_form is a part of wtforms not a part of flask ext ?

Answer (score 12):

You're passing a form **class** not a form **instance** to the template. The `model_form` method generates a new class dynamically, which can be re-used, extended, and otherwise used like any other form subclass. It's also quite un-necessary to generate this form class on every run of your view, so you can move this call outside of your view.

You passing an uninstantiated class is also why you get strange behavior relating to UnboundField (which is how WTForms handles declarative field instantiation)

The fix is simple:

```
MemberForm = model_form(Member, base_class=Form)

@simple_page.route('/register')
def register():
    form = MemberForm(name=u'bad')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to do a bit more work:

```
{{ form.name.label }} : {{ form.name()|safe }}
```

Or, you can use this [handy snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates):

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Of course, adjust the HTML rendered. Save that file somewhere in your `templates` directory and then in your main template. Here its `formhelpers.html`:

```
{% from "formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post action="/register">
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.name) }}
    {{ render_field(form.email) }}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Register>
</form>
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, i get: TypeError: 'Unbound Field' object is not callable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but I had the same problem and I want to share my solution for futures needs.

I also got the html rendered by "UnboundField". After fighting with the code I found out i'm using:

```
from wtforms import Form
```

And it's looks good, but when using Flask I had to do this:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

Fixed my problem. Hope it's helped